# Else statement being executed when user enters in keyword that matches string

Tags: c#

I have this C# zoo program where user enters in a animal and the program will print out the viewing time for the animal.

At the moment I have two animals; scorpion and lion

```
using System;

namespace TheZoo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string scorpion = null;
            string lion = null;
            Console.WriteLine("###################################################\n");
            Console.WriteLine("----------You are now using Zoo--------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("###################################################\n");
            Console.WriteLine("**********Press any key to continue****************\n");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the list of animals that are available to see today: \n");
            Console.WriteLine("/////Animal/////         " + "/////Location/////         ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. scorpion              " + "Desert East Side           ");
            Console.WriteLine("2. lion                  " + "Plains West Side           ");
            /*Console.WriteLine("3. grizzly bear          " + "Forest South Side          ");
            Console.WriteLine("4. cheetah               " + "Plains East Side           ");
            Console.WriteLine("5. redback spider        " + "Gardens North Side         ");
            Console.WriteLine("6. snow leopard          " + "Arctic South Side          ");
            Console.WriteLine("7. anaconda              " + "Plains South Side          ");
            Console.WriteLine("8. alligator             " + "Lakes West Side            ");
            Console.WriteLine("9. polar bear            " + "Arctic North Side          ");*/
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in the animal to see the time of that animals exhibition (e.g. Enter duck if you wish to see the time for duck)");
            scorpion = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            
            if (scorpion == "scorpion")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The viewing time for scorpion today will be at 09:30 ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a valid number");
            }

            if (lion == "lion")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The viewing time for lion today will be at 10:30 ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a valid number");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program and enter "scorpion" in console, I receive the following output from the console

"The viewing time for scorpion today will be at 09:30
Please enter in a valid number"

The else ["Please enter in a valid number"] is triggered even though I have entered in the animal name

I tried changing the else to an else if, however I did not have luck with this

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit and post the code in the question instead of images or links.

Comment: I edit the post @Zer0

Comment: I think your need to use `else if (lion == "lion")`  as it will check first `if (scorpion == "scorpion")` but IMO a `case` would be better to use.

Comment: `lion` is always null. So the second check (`if (lion == "lion")` always switches to its else block.
Maybe you wanted to assign the user input to lion like `lion = Console.ReadLine()` or you want the menu to run in a loop....

Comment: This is a logic error that you can easily figure out by stepping through the code in the debugger. If you don't know how to use one, now is an excellent time to learn. A debugger is one of the most powerful tools in a programmer's arsenal, and it's never too early to learn how to use that tool.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is nothing to prevent the code from executing if the user indeed have entered a "scorpion" currently the code will always check for "scorpion" and "lion" so the result you get is expected. In terms of executions it's something like this:

- User enters value "scorpion"
- if check for "scoprion" is true and the code inside the if-block is executed in the console is printed "The viewing time for scorpion today will be at 09:30 "
- There is nothing that stops the code from executing after the match so the first else is skipped and the code is executing the second check of "lion"
- The if check for "lion" is false so the code inside the else-block is executed. In the console is printed "Please enter in a valid number"

Pretty much, this is the algorithm of your program so the result is very logical. An easy fix would be to have something like

```
var animal = = Console.ReadLine();

if (animal == "scorpion")
{
  Console.WriteLine("The viewing time for scorpion today will be at 09:30 ");
}
else if (animal == "lion")
{
  Console.WriteLine("The viewing time for lion today will be at 10:30 ");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter in a valid number");
}
```

Few quick advices:

- When you get the user input choose more generic variable name. A scorpion is type of animal and you want to check for different kind of animals. Thus I'm using `var animal` since it can be both scorpion or a lion
- When you get the input it's good to have some sort of validation. In your case maybe that only upper and lower characters were used
- When you perform the if checks it makes sense to me me to be case insensitive since both Scorpion and scorpion should be valid IMO so you can use `animal.Equals("scorpion", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Can't think of anything else at the moment.

P.S
Currently your program will terminate after the first input (match or no match). You can add additional level of complexity by introducing some loop which will prompt for animal name until the user enters a valid one for example.